# Proof by induction that $(a^n-1)$ is divisible by $(a-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I have to proof that $(a^n-1)$ is divisible by $(a-1)$ where $a \in \mathbb {N_{>1}}$

I think that I have the proof but I am not sure if that is the correct format.

**Induction hypothesis:** $(a^n-1)=x(a-1)$ where $x \in \mathbb {N}$

When $n=0$ and $x=0$ each side will be $0$

**To be proofed**: $(a^{n+1}-1)=m(a-1)$ where $m \in \mathbb {N}$

**Proof:**

$(a^n-1)=x(a-1)$

$a^n=x(a-1)+1$

$a*a^n=a \left ( x \left ( a-1\right ) + 1\right )$

$a^{n+1}-1= a \left ( x \left ( a-1\right ) + 1\right ) -1=a(xa-x+1)-1=xa^2-xa+a-1=\underbrace{(xa+1)}_\textrm{m}(a-1)$

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I realize this is a bit of thread necromancy, but: As a gentle grammar correction (not a criticism): For this sense, we usually use the verb "to prove", with past participle either "proved" or "proven".  "Proof" can be a verb, but it then generally means either to secure (especially against water), to inspect for errors, or to produce a copy of something for inspection.

Comment: $a^n-1=(a-1)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+1\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. I give another proof:

Let's see $a^n-1$ as a polynomial $P$ with indeterminate $a$ so the polynomial 
$$P(a)=a^n-1$$
vanishes at $a=1$ hence $1$ is a (simple since $P'(1)\ne0$) root of $P$ and then $a-1$ divides $P(a)$.

Comment: But then you have to have proved the results about polynomials, which makes this a much more complicated proof.