# Prove by induction that $8^{n} − 1$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove by induction that $8^{n} − 1$ for any positive integer $n$ is divisible by $7$.

Hint: It is easy to represent divisibility by $7$ in the following way: $8^{n} − 1 = 7 \cdot k$ where k is a positive integer.

This question confused me because I think the hint isn't true. If $n = 1$ and $k = 2$ for example, then we end up with $7 = 14$ which is obviously invalid. Does this mean the $n \leq k$ in order for the hint to be true.

Comment: Not **any** $k$, but **a** "suitable" $k$; with $n=1, 8^1-1=7=7 \times 1$, and thus $k=1$. With $n=2, 8^2-1=63=7 \times 9$, and so on.

Comment: start with $n=0$ or $n=1$

Comment: This is a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565311/proof-by-induction-for-divisibility, which in turn is a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607176/xn-yn-is-divisible-by-x-y-mathematical-induction

Comment: @DavidK: I noticed that!

Comment: $8^n-1=7\left(8^{n-1}+8^{n-2}+\cdots+1\right)$.

Comment: @BrianTung I just happened to have been looking at one of those links moments earlier. It would be much easier to notice these things if people put the specific question in the titles of these posts (i.e., "Prove ____ by induction" rather than "Proof by induction - help me!"). This set me off on a question-editing rampage today, which I hope didn't cause too much disruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the following steps of mathematical induction,

1. Setting $n=1$, $$8^1-1=7$$ above number is divisible by $7$ for $n=1$
2. assume that $8^n-1$ is divisible by $7$ for $n=k$ then $$8^k-1=7m$$
   or $$8^k=7m+1\tag 1$$
   where, $m$ is some integer
3. setting $n=k+1$, $$8^{k+1}-1$$
   $$=8\cdot 8^k-1$$
   setting the value of $8^k$ from (1), $$=8(7m+1)-1$$
   $$=7(8m+1)$$

since, $(8m+1)$ is an integer hence the number $7(8m+1)$ is divisible by $7$ thus $8^n-1$ is divisible by $7$ for $n=k+1$

hence, $8^n-1$ is divisible by $7$ for all integers $n\ge 1$

Answer (score 3):

$$8^{n+1}-1=7\cdot8^n+8^n-1\equiv 8^n-1\mod 7$$ and $$8^0-1=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

let $$T_k=8^k-1$$ then $$T_{k+1}=8(8^k-1)+7$$

Answer (score 2):

Proving $7 | 8^n - 1$ is the same as proving $8^n - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

**Prove**:

> If $n \geq 1$, we see that $8 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, so using module $7$: $$8^n - 1 \equiv
>  0 \iff 1^n - 1 \equiv 0$$    which is obviously true as $1^n$ is
>   always $1$ for $n\geq 1$. $\qquad \square$